# Cocoa radio buttons disappear when clicked

Tags: cocoa

I have a window with two radio buttons. When I click one of them, both disappear. The "selected" highlight remains. If the windows looses focus and I switch back, the buttons return, only to disappear again when I click one of them.

I'm quite lost, I don't even know where to begin. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: my suggestion will be to paste a code :)

Comment: Post the code, so we can help you with a suggestion.